# Ignore subsequent equivalent rows in mysql select

Tags: mysql, sql, logging, data-cleaning, redundancy

I need to remove redundancy in historical log data. So given the following table:

```
 --------------------------------------
|  entity_id  |  action  |   date      |
 --------------------------------------
|      1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-01  |
|x     1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-01  |
|      1      |    'B'   | 2018-01-01  |
|      1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-02  |
|      8      |    'A'   | 2018-01-02  |
|x     1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-03  |
|x     8      |    'A'   | 2018-01-04  |
|x     1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-05  |
|      1      |    'B'   | 2018-01-05  |
 --------------------------------------
```

I want to remove the ones with (x). In short, I would like to ignore any rows with same action that an entity has taken subsequently. Therefore, I would like a query that returns the following result

```
 --------------------------------------
|  entity_id  |  action  |   date      |
 --------------------------------------
|      1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-01  |
|      1      |    'B'   | 2018-01-01  |
|      1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-02  |
|      8      |    'A'   | 2018-01-02  |
|      1      |    'B'   | 2018-01-05  |
 --------------------------------------
```

Programmatically, it is easy to remove those redundancies, but with pure SQL, I'm a bit lost. How would someone knowledgeable enough with SQL queries handle this?

Thanks

edit: Basically, for entity 1, the succession of actions in the log is `A->A->B->A->A->A->B`, I would like a select that returns the row with these actions `A->B->A->B`

Comment: Why do you exclude  `1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-03` and `1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-05` but keep `1      |    'A'   | 2018-01-02`?

Comment: Because `(1, 'B', 2018-01-02)` has happened. Basically, for entity `1`, the succession of actions in the log is `A->A->B->A->A->A->B`, I would like a select that returns the row with these actions `A->B->A->B`. I'll probably add this to the edit

Comment: In your desired sample you have `A>B>A>A>B`

Comment: The 4th row belongs to entity `8`. I included `8` to show that the logs is comprised by different entities. And other entities' subsequent actions should be ignored too.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which renders problems like this essentially insoluble (or at least, meaningless).

Comment: How does a primary key help?

Comment: @adamaMG data is stored in unordered fashion; in your case, without Primary key, we really cannot determine which comes first and which comes later; especially in case of ties.

Answer (score 0):

This would be if the rows are added in the order of the date.

```
select entity_id, action, min(date)
from table
group by entity id, action
```

Comment: The first query seems to only pick one row per action for the entity (i.e. once it has seen a (1, 'A') row, it will ignore all the others, even non-subsequent ones).

Comment: The second query fails with the following sql error `Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'date' `

Answer (score -1):

You want rows with the most recent action for each entity.  I would do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select min(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.entity_id = t.entity_id and t2.action = t.action
               );
```

EDIT:

In MySQL 8+, you would simply use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(action) over (partition by entity_id order by date) as prev_action
      from t
     ) t
where prev_action is null or prev_action > action;
```

You can do something similar in previous versions of MySQL, but window functions are simpler if available.

Comment: *You want rows with the most recent action for each entity* no the OP does not want this for sure if you see at the sample he posted.

Comment: @forpas . . . Did you really downvote the answer because it used `MAX()` instead of `MIN()`?  A simple comment suffices.

Comment: Also neither MIN is the issue I think after the OP's edit